# CSS not showing up

Tags: css, html

My external style sheet:

```
body {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
background-color: #4d4d4d; }
 }


#reflection {
background-color: #fff;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 100%;
height: 257px;
 }

#main {
border-top: 20px solid #494949;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 90px;
height: 330px;
background-color: #eee;
 }
```

My index page

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<head>
<title>P.S.</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="main">
HERE'S THE MAIN PART!</div>
<div id="reflection">Here's the reflection.</div> </body>
```

The div "reflection"'s css styling doesn't seem to show up. I haven't a clue as to why. I've been working at it for hours!

Comment: Extraneous } in the definition of "body"? That might be screwing up parsing of the rest of the style sheet.

Answer (score 3):

```
body {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
background-color: #4d4d4d; }
 }
```

Please see above css. 2 time closed. please remove and check it.
and also missed `<html>`

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.ps.niu-niu.org/ps.css

```
.reflection {
background-color: #fff;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 100%;
height: 257px;
 }
```

and from your question

```
#reflection {
background-color: #fff;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 100%;
height: 257px;
background-image: url('http://www.ps.niu-niu.org/shine.png');
 }
```

update the server same code as your question

Answer (score 1):

The css file is malformed.... there is an extra `}` at the end of `body`.

```
body {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
background-color: #4d4d4d; } /* extra bracket HERE */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/thilakar/yKX4v/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your `reflection` is an id. You're referring to it as a class in the css.

EDIT: This is looking at the live view, by the way. Make sure you have actually applied the changes to your server.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `<html>` element in your markup as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/your/stylesheet.css>` in the `<head>`